# How to get individual group totals in report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report being made with *iReport*, which is basically a list of pages received the day prior. The report has total pages for the whole day and then individual totals for each group of page types.

The requirements state I need to display all the totals *above* the listed records and groups (ex. display in the title band). I created a variable for the total of all pages and that works but am having trouble getting each individual group total.

It should look like:

```
Total pages received: 50
Total GROUP_A: 20    Total GROUP_B: 30
```

When I try to use the variable set up for group totals, it only gives me the last used group, so it would say 30. I'm unsure how to create a variable to get the total for only a specific group.

I could include in my SQL result set the totals but was asked to do it within *iReport*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Displaying static text instead of empty group in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105588/displaying-static-text-instead-of-empty-group-in-jasperreports)

--should add this isn't exactly a duplicate question, but It look like that answer might also work for you?

Comment: @Neil Tried using the info in your referenced answer but that is about putting things in groups. I can get a group total in the group bands, but I need individualized group totals before any group bands (so it always displays once, top of the report). I'm not sure how to create a custom summation variable to do this. Or maybe I misinterpreted the referenced answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17495038/subdataset-total-rows-in-the-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem right you need to put a copy of the variable that you are using in the group and put it in your title band.  the trick is on the object in the title band make sure you have set the **evaluation time** &  **evaluation group**  group or report depending on what you are truing to get a total of.

Comment: Being I only have two groups possible, this worked. For the first group, evaluation time "Group" totals the first group. For the second group, evaluation time "Report" totals the last group. If I had a third group, I'm not sure how I would get the total for the group in-between first and last.